# Finding the radius of convergence in Analysis - root or ratio test? Are they equal?

Tags: limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

So I am trying to solve this task:
[task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoHcc.png)

And using the Theorem of Cauchy-Hadamard also called root test, I get 1/0 as n goes to infinity. Thats because the limit of the series is 0, as you can see [here.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fbngfx8plx)
And since the Theorem of Cauchy-Hadamard defines 1/0 = infinity, that means that the radius of converges is infinity.

However, the solution to this task given by my university is this:
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obto2.png)

Quotient criterion here means ratio test. Now I dont understand how the root and ratio test can give such different results. Somebody must be doin something wrong here, but I really can not see any mistakes on my behalf.

Would really appreciate any help here!

Comment: There was a recent question about $\sum\limits_n \frac{n!}{n^n}x^n$ (I made a comment about Stirling's approximation to the factorial, which suggests a radius of convergence of $e$ but I cannot find it now

Comment: $\frac{n!}{n^n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ does not imply the series converges: consider $\frac1n \to 0$ while $\sum \frac1n$ diverges. In any case, $\frac{n!}{n^n}x^n \not \to 0$ when $x$ is large enough: try it with $x=10$

Comment: Hey @Henry thanks for your comments, however I dont know if they help me that much… In this task I dont have to show if the series converges but only have to give the radius of convergence. And well, (n!/n^n)^1/n does converge to zero, at least if I put this into desmos… So, the calculations giving e as the result look perfeclty logical, however I really just can not wrap this around my mind… EDIT: I am appetently wrong, it does not converge to 0 but in fact to 0.37 which is 1/e

Comment: In Desmos you forgot to take the nth root. The Desmos graph is quite different if you include that part. By the way, Desmos stops being able to compute the function after about $n=143$.

Comment: @DavidK Yes you are right! I edited my comment, seems like my problem was not taking the nth root all along... Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See @Henry's comment, you are doing the root test wrong. The root and ratio tests are not equivalent: [the root test is more difficult to compute but also more powerful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests): whenever the ratio test shows convergence, the root test does too; whenever the root test is inconclusive, the ratio test is too. In this case, they must yield the same result. For the root test,
\begin{align}
\alpha&=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{n!}{n^n}\right|^{1\over n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n!)^{\frac1n}}{n}\\&=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\log(n!)-\log n}\\
&=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}(\log1+\log2+\dots+\log n)-\frac{n\log n}{n}}\\
&=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\frac1n+\log\frac2n+\dots+\log\frac{n}{n}}{n}}\\&=e^{\int_{0}^1\log xdx}\qquad\text{Definition of the definite integral}\\&={1\over e}
\end{align}
Therefore, the radius of convergence is $r=e$.

Comment: Thanks @ricky but I really do not understand the likes 3-5 in your calculation, I am not that good with e and log… would appreciate if you could somehow simplify your solution

Comment: I've added some detail. You should look up the property of the logarithm elsewhere.